# Hibernate Replicate with different databases MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two tables, the first has the columns
table1:

```
Id
name
description
status
url
```

The second has the columns:
table2:

```
Id
status
url
```

Is it possible to use the Hibernate Replicate method to do:
selection all from table1 -> insert only some columns in table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Replicate` is to persist the data objects in a different data store without regenerating the identities.

Basically you detach the object from one data store and attach it to another data store.

While doing so your `Entity` object is same, so basically you need same structure.

If you want to avoid that then you need to create separate entities for each tables and copy the data between them using getter/setters.

[For more information on Hibernate Replicate.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-replicating)

Comment: yeah, i readed that, i want to replicate the identities, i was looking for some way to avoid creating two entities but i think its not possible, thanks thought!